# Keep track of values in a dictionary while performing multprocessing Pool

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, multiprocessing

Here is a sample of the code:

```
    my_dict = {}
    for elem in some_file.my_dict:
        my_dict[elem] = my_dict.get(elem, {'value1': 0, 'value2': 'UP'})
    static_var = generate_static_var()

    pool = Pool(processes = 99)
    chunks = [(static_var, list(my_dict)[i::99]) for i in range(99)]

    failed_responses = pool.map(generate_separate_var, chunks)
```

The first process in the pool is fine because the local dictionary will not be different until that first process completes. However, since I am doing a multiprocessing Pool, there are 99 threads running simultaneously, thus the values that are being returned after the first process completes are being lost by the 99th process completion. Is there a way to make sure you do not lose out on the values returned after each process completes?

Comment: It is generally not considered useful to specify many more processes for a `Pool` than you CPU has cores because in that case the worker processes will be starved for processing time.

Comment: this runs on a server where the max threads available are 160 before entering thrashing. the only reason i was doing 99 threads because I was using a psycopg2 connector to create a tunnel to a database, which only allows 99 open connections at a given time.

Comment: Even if the database allows 99 connections, are you sure it can  serve that many concurrent reads or writes? Unless this is a stress-test for the database in question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For a `Pool.map()` to work properly, the function used in the map should take one parameter (which could be a data structure), do some calculations based *only* on that input and return one result (which could also be a data structure).

When programmed in this way, the given function "maps" the input iterable to a result iterable.